# in flutter how to filter data using text from field

Tags: flutter, search, filter, full-text-search, textfield

`code`

this is text from field code i want filter this from after get value from user, data variable have all data list i want to find search data from this data variable

```
var data = [];
var si=[];
 setState(() {
            si.addAll(data.where((element) => element.containsValue(textFieldController)));
          });

 Widget from(){
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(           
              controller: textFieldController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),   
                labelText: "From",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),   
                
                )          
              ),           
            
    );
  }
```

Comment: `element.containsValue(textFieldController.text)`

Comment: Thanks sir It's now working